# Stable navigation bar inside of a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

How would I go about adding a bar at the bottom of my screen that remains there while the rest of my view is scrollable? My root view is a ScrollView, so I'm assuming anything within it is scrollable but I can't put anything else outside it seems without it telling me I have multiple root tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please check out the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) for more information. It was released in API level 21 and is in the support library v7.

Comment: Do you know how I could attach the toolbar to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: The layout provided will attach a toolbar to the bottom of the screen below the scroll view.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `Didn't find class "android.view.Toolbar"` I think it has to do with API level do you know what I would do to support this?

Comment: @Brejuro Ahh Toolbar is in the support library I have update the code.

Comment: I tried that out but it seems like it also doesn't work. I think I'm using android support v4?

Comment: Include `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` in your gradle build file

Comment: I think that will do it but Aside from those errors this layout will in fact put whatever layout you want below your scroll view and should solve your original problem. The implementation of the toolbar is something you should look up and attempt. Please post a new question if you are stuck implementing the toolbar.